# Behaviour when storing std::thread in vectors

Tags: c++

Similar questions have been asked before, however none seem to be explaining some behavior I observed. Some answers have already explained why you need to have the vector of pointers to threads (copy vs move). A few follow up questions:

1. I'm trying to instantiate the pointers in a temp variable and push the temp variable to the vector. It fails, but works when using `std::move` or when putting the whole instantiation in the `push_back()`. Why is `std::move` necessary since `push_back()` has the const reference as the argument, i.e. what's the difference?
2. Why does accessing threads by subscription `greeters[i]` throw a segmentation fault? The program runs for a few iterations and then crashes?
3. Similar to above but with iterators. Only using `back()` seems to work fine. Does it have anything to do with the const reference return type? If so what?

Compile using `g++ -std=c++20 -pthread -o thread thread.cpp`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

std::mutex m;
int cnt = 0;


void say_hello(int id)
{
    m.lock();
    cnt++;
    std::cout << cnt << " Hello from " << id << std::endl;
    m.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    int n = 20;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> greeters(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      // auto tmp = std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread( [&i]() { return say_hello(i); } ) );
      // greeters.push_back(tmp); // error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at'

      // greeters.push_back(std::move(tmp)); // works fine
      greeters.push_back(std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread( [&i]() { return say_hello(i); } ) ));  // works fine
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
      auto val = std::move(greeters[i]); // throws segmentation fault
      // auto val = std::move(greeters.back()); // works fine
      // greeters.pop_back();
      val -> join();
    }

    // std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>>::iterator ptr;
    // for (ptr = greeters.begin(); ptr < greeters.end(); ptr++) {
    //   (*ptr) -> join(); // throws segmentation fault
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `m.lock();` is really not safe though. What happens if your program throws an exception and `m` is never unlocked? You better avoid using `lock` directly on a mutex.

Comment: Fair point, thanks for noticing. What would you suggest as a better approach?

Comment: Re: "you ... need to have the vector of pointers to threads" -- this isn't true.

Comment: @toni057 There are different options. Maybe [std::scoped_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock).

Comment: Thanks @digito_evo , I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 2):

The bug has nothing to do with vectors or threads, per se. The constructor was wrong.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> greeters(n);
```

This creates a vector with 20 values, which will be empty `unique_ptr`s.

This is what this constructor does. The `n` parameter to `std::vector`'s constructor specifies the initialize size of the vector, which gets default-initialized. With `unique_ptr`s, the default-initialization results in null `unique_ptr`s.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      greeters.push_back...
```

This ends up `push_back`ing twenty more `unique_ptr`s to the vector. It now has 40 `unique_ptr`s. The first twenty of them are null pointers.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
      auto val = std::move(greeters[i]); // throws segmentation fault
      val -> join();
    }
```

This iterates over the first 20 `unique_ptr`s in the vector, which a are null, and attempts to dereference the null ptrs in a futile attempt to `join` them. This ends in tears, and segmentation faults.

I should mention one more comment: I also did not immediately see the bug in the shown program, right away. But I simply loaded your program in my debugger, set a breakpoint, and the bug became obvious in just a few seconds:

```
(gdb) p greeters
$2 = std::vector of length 40, capacity 40 = {std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {
    get() = 0x0}, std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x0}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x418f60}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x419220}, 
  std::unique_ptr<std::thread> = {get() = 0x418f80},
...
```

Why is this vector twice as large as it should be, and why is the first half of it empty `unique_ptr`s? Oh...

This is why it's a good idea to invest some time in learning how to use a debugger in order to be able to solve these Scooby-Doo mysteries, all by yourself.

Comment: Yikes, what a silly mistake :(. When getting rid of the n works fine. Though I'm still a  it puzzled since I see some output before the segmentation fault, and I was looping only over the first n empty pointers.

Comment: Yes, you successfully started the threads, and they managed to get their output out the door before the whole thing crapped out. The bug does not happen until after all the threads are created, and are already running.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all that indirection. It's not needed. You **can** and **should** create vectors of threads and not go through two layers of indirection:

```
[temp]$ cat test.cpp
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> vec;
    std::thread thr;
    vec.push_back(std::move(thr));
    std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
    return 0;
}
[temp]$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
[temp]$ ./a.out
Hello, world
[temp]$
```

Comment: This was exactly my initial idea, however couldn't get it to work. Thanks for sharing. So what is it about `std::move` that it can make it work and just a simple assignment cannot? ie what different mechanisms are triggered?

Comment: @toni057 -- `std::thread` objects are not copyable, but they're movable. It wouldn't make sense to copy a thread object, because then there would be two objects managing the same thread. Same issue with `std::unique_ptr`; if you could copy it it wouldn't be unique.

Comment: @toni057 "std::thread is not CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable, although it is MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable." From [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). That's why a `std::move` is required to invoke the *move* constructor or the *move* assignment operator of class `std::thread`.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. However how does `std::move` know where the new memory address inside the vector is? I'm presuming there has to be some physical copying followed by releasing old memory space.

Comment: `std::move` doesn't know or care where the object is ending up. Movable types have a move constructor and a move assignment operator that handle moving from one object to another. `std::move` (oversimplified) says to use the move versions rather than the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator.

Comment: Ok, so which component actually lands the object with the state in the exact memory address inside the vector? Is it `vector::push_back` and by using MoveConstructible mechanism instead of copy when using assignment?

Comment: @toni057 `std::move` has a misleading name. It does not move anything. It only performs a simple cast just like `static_cast<T&&>(t)` and that tells the compiler that it can call the move constructor or the move assignment operator depending on which one is needed. By using `push_back` in `vec.push_back(std::move(thr));` you are creating a new instance of `std::thread` by move constructing it based on `thr` object's attributes.